# Give a sequence such that its set of accumulation points is [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Give a sequence $x_n$ such that its set of accumulation points is  $[0,1]$ (interval in $\mathbb{R}$)  . Is it there a sequence $y_n$ such that its set of accumulation points is $Y = (0,1)$?

I am struggling to define $x_n$. I have thought of something like $x_n= |\sin(n)|$, but then I can't find a way to *proof* that this would work. Also, as far as I know, it should be a divergent sequence right? Because if it was convergent then it would only have one accumulation point.

As for the second question, suppose we have $y_n$, then $\forall\epsilon>0$ we get that $A = (0, 0 + \epsilon] \subset Y$ , thus $0$ is an accumulation point of $y_n$, a contradiction since $0 \not \in Y$. Therefore $y_n$ can't exist.

How could I prove the first question? Is my second aswer correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could enumerate the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: If you want $(y_n)_n$ such that its set of cluster points is exactly $\mathopen]0\mathbin;1\mathclose[$, I fear that no such sequence exists since the set of cluster points is **always closed**. (Just generalize your second point to prove that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  stated in the comments, you can take an enumaration of rationals in $[0,1]$
and use density.

Another example is the set $\{n\sqrt{2}-[n\sqrt{2}]:n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ which is dense in $[0,1]$

For the second question:

Your solution is fine.

In general the  set of accumulation points of a bounded sequence is always a closed set.

Let $x_n$  a bounded sequence on the real line

and $K=\{x \in \Bbb{R}: \text{x is an accumulation point of } x_n\}$

As an exercise prove that  $K$ is a closed set.

Comment: If you consider $K=[0\mathbin;1]\smallsetminus\big\{\frac12\big\}$ then: $\inf K\in K$ and $\sup K\in K$, but $K$ is not closed.

Comment: @jpboucheron i edited thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about $|\sin n|$.

It is a well-known fact that any non-zero subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ has the form $(a\mathbb{Z}, +)$ (for some real $a>0$) or else is *dense*.
Since $2\pi\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}=\{2m\pi+n \mid (m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\}$ cannot be $a\mathbb{Z}$ (because $\pi$ is irrational), it is dense.
Thus for any $t\in\big[0;\frac\pi2\big]$ and any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists integers $m$, $n$ such that $|t-(2m\pi+n)|\leqslant\varepsilon$.
We then use the fact that $|\sin x-\sin y|\leqslant|x-y|$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ (mean value inequality) to obtain:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\big||\sin t|-|\sin n|\big|&\leqslant&|\sin t - \sin n|\\
&=&|\sin t - \sin(2m\pi+n)|\\
&\leqslant&|t-(2m\pi+n)|\\
&\leqslant&\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since any element $x\in[0\mathbin;1]$ has the form $x=\sin t$, for $t=\arcsin x\in\big[0;\frac\pi2\big]$, we conclude that such a $x$ is an accumulation point for the sequence $(|\sin n|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.